# Uploaded image not being stored properly in the database (php mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, store

I am trying to store uploaded images in the database. However, the images won't display, and when i take a look at the table with phpmyadmin in the image column i see stuff like [BLOB - 20B] instead of the actual size it should have.

The display script works fine, as i inserted an image through phpmyadmin instead of my upload script and it displayed fine.

My form:

```
<form id="productForm" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="' . $values['product_id'] . '" />
<input type="file" name="image" />
</form>
```

Processing code:

```
$clean['image'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));

mysqli_query($dbc, "
  INSERT INTO product_images (product_id, mime, image)
  VALUES ('{$clean['last_product_id']}', '{$clean['mime']}', '{$clean['image']}')
");
```

I have omitted everything that is irrelevant cause the other things seem to be working well.

Thanks

Comment: `[BLOB - 20B]` is phpMyAdmin's placeholder for BLOB data. Is there a problem displaying the images?

Comment: Well the way i see it, it's telling me that there are only 20 bytes stored! These images don't display. The one i added manually from phpmyadmin says 92KB or something and displays fine.

Comment: Updated my answer with some code to try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it had something to do with the escaping. I ended up not escaping anything until the actual query, which i formed with sprintf()

```
$clean['qText'] = sprintf("
  INSERT INTO product_images (product_id, mime, image)
  VALUES ('%d', '%s', '%s')",

  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $clean['last_product_id']),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $clean['mime']),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
);

mysqli_query($dbc, $clean['qText']);
```

Comment: Now click the green checkmark by this answer to "accept it".  You don't want to leave open-ended questions around... the more you do, the less people will be willing to answer your future questions.  :)

Comment: Eventually i ended up using the filesystem though. There were some drawbacks from using the db, like no cacheing for example, which made the whole thing sorta slow. :)

Answer (score 2):

My apologies that this is not a direct answer to your question, but I would suggest that your approach is not the best one - to the point that I advise you to abandon it if you can.

Storing image data in the database is possible, but it's one of those things that you CAN do, but shouldn't.  If your script sees even moderate use, your database can quickly become large and unwieldy. Especially with poor or missing indexes, you can expect your database performance to decline as the table size bloats with each added record.

Added to the database size, there's the additional complexity of maintaining code that can retrieve the image data and output it in a manner that can be used by the client.  You aren't going to be able to just `print` the data, you'll have to send headers to indicate it is an image, which means a separate script, extra http requests, and additional database call.

All around, this is a bad method to use.  You're FAR better off writing the file to disk, then storing the path as a string in the database, which is, might I add, much easier to do from a code perspective.  It is also infinitely easier to utilize the data later, as well.

Best of luck!

**EDIT**

Try this to correct your current code, by the way:

```
$instr = fopen($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"rb");
    $image = addslashes(fread($instr,filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])));
    mysqli_query($dbc, 'INSERT INTO product_images (product_id, mime, image)
      VALUES ("'.$clean['last_product_id'].'", "'.$clean['mime'].'", "'.$image.'")';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have a system like the one you described, but i just want to check out the alternative. No harm in that i think :-)

Comment: Plus the limits on packet size on the client<->server protocol - files can easily exceed the limit and kill the connection.

Comment: @Booya No, no harm in experimentation with other methods.  But, I would argue that one ought to always endeavor to work on *improvement* of their current methods.  It hardly makes sense, for example, for a guy with a magnifying glass to experiment with bashing rocks together to make a fire.  He ought to be looking in to lighters.  You gain nothing by learning a method that is a step backwards from your current method.

Comment: @Chris
Well the thing is, i have seen advocates of both, so i want to see it for myself and judge.

Comment: @Marc B
The funny thing is that i managed to make a totally simplistic script with just the essnetials and it worked, but the same things are not working on my normal page and i can't figure out why. The other things on the page have nothing to do with this.

Comment: Can you give a link to an article where someone advocates storing images in the database that was not written in 1991?  If so, I really do want the link, as I'd like to see what possible justification can be offered.

Comment: On the contrary, there is nothing inherently wrong with storing binary data, such as image files, in a database, if you have a need for the features database storage will provide. Yes, it places an extra load on the database if you use it to replicate a simple file system, and yes it is not generally the correct choice for simpler projects. But there are issues of reliability and management and scaling that don't magically go away when you put uploaded images in the file system.

Comment: By the way i have found a solution, though i still didn't find the cause of the problem, but i suspect it had something to do with the escaping. I used a different query format, using sprintf(), without escaping anything prior to the actual query:

Comment: Sorry for the messed up code i cant figure out how to format it

$clean['qText'] = sprintf("
INSERT INTO product_images (product_id, mime, image)
VALUES ('%d', '%s', '%s')",
mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $clean['last_product_id']),
mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $clean['mime']),
mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
);

mysqli_query($dbc, $clean['qText']);

Comment: I guessed that the problem was coming from the parsed double-quote syntax, or the escape function.  The sample code I put in there uses `addSlashes` as well as single-quote strings to try and avoid both techniques.  Probably one of those two things were polluting the binary data.  You should post your solution as a new answer and accept it!

Comment: Paste it into a new answer rather than a comment... :)